# Will this cause a reference to point to nothing after it goes out of scope?

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, scope

Is the following code safe?

```
class B {
  public:
    int& b;
    B (int& _b) :
      b(_b) {}
};

B* foo() {
  int a;
  return new B(a);
}
```

Will the reference in the object returned by foo point to nothing (since int a is going out of scope) or does the compile figure this out?

Comment: `B::b` will be a dangling reference as local variable `a` no longer exists when `foo()` returns, as you already state.

Comment: See 17.6.4.3.2/2: *Each name that begins with an underscore is reserved to the implementation for use as a name in the
global namespace.*. Use `b_` instead.

Comment: @dirkgently, that name isn't in the global namespace, the name is ok

Comment: @dirkgently: http://stackoverflow.com/a/228797/14065

Comment: @owagh: In the standard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/14065 Though most people will usually tell you what version as section numbers may change slightly between version, though section names will remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler might warn you, but the newly created object definitely contains a dangling, invalid reference, as the object `a` stops existing at the end of the scope of `foo`.